# Update all JSONB scoped array elements depending on type

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've got the following schema:

| id::UUID | payload::JSONB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "A", "value": 1 }, {"type": "B", "value": 2 }] }] |
| 2 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "A", "value": 1 }, {"type": "A", "value": 2 }] }] |
| 3 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "B", "value": 1 }] }] |
| 4 | [{ "edits": [] }] |

For each element of `payload` I need to update `value` to be an object. That object slightly differs given the type:

`CASE type = A => value: { src: <prevVal> }`
`CASE type = B => value: { url: <prevVal> }`

For the above example, I expect to get:

| id::UUID | payload::JSONB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "A", "value": { "src": 1 }}, {"type": "B", "value": { "url": 2 } }] }] |
| 2 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "A", "value": { "src": 1 }}, {"type": "A", "value": { "src": 2 } }] }] |
| 3 | [{ "edits": [{"type": "B", "value": { "url": 1 } }] }] |
| 4 | [{ "edits": [] }] |

Comment: Is `payload` always an array containing a single object with an `edits` property?

Comment: correct @Bergi `payload` is always an array with **exactly** 1 element. That 1 element will always have an `edits` property. `edits` can be an empty array tho

Comment: Then you can use @stefanov's solution with `jsonb_array_elements(payload->0->'edits')` and `SET payload = jsonb_set(payload, '{0,edits}', (select …))`

Comment: That makes sense, I think that doesn't fully cover the `"edits": []` case, but maybe it's a quick COALESCE fix. Will try it out tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: To skip `[{"edits":[]}]` records you may use a `where` clause in the update query, `where payload->0->'edits'->0 is not null`. Simpler and cleaner than a `coalesce` approach.

Answer (score 1):

First flatten the `payload` array and then rebuild it with the new `value`.

```sql
update the_table set payload =  
 (select jsonb_agg(p || jsonb_build_object(  
    'value', jsonb_build_object
    (
     case when p ->> 'type' = 'A' then 'src' else 'url' end, 
     (p ->> 'value')::integer
    )
  ))    
  from jsonb_array_elements(payload) p
 );

select * from the_table;
```

| id | payload |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"type": "A", "value": {"src": 1}}, {"type": "B", "value": {"url": 2}}] |
| 2 | [{"type": "A", "value": {"src": 1}}, {"type": "A", "value": {"src": 2}}] |
| 3 | [{"type": "B", "value": {"url": 1}}] |

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c92xrzugmvHmtWSXeenRTF/0).
Unrelated but JSON is not valid in your examples.

Comment: Apologies, I'm just realising that the array in my example is incorrect... The array is wrapped within another array; unfortunately, the solution does not translate well. I've updated the example. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I think i managed to get to a solution, following your example, but I find it very hard to read: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3BA7LSJwftBXRyrRbUwys/0 any suggestions?